# new openni.launch file --> topic gone

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Since the last update the topic

/camera/depth_registered/image

is gone. I used this, because the depth values were in meter.

When I disable registration i have the topic

/camera/depth/image

But this doesn't help me, because i need the registered image. It seems like the update somehow removed the /camera/depth_registered/image topic. Only /camera/depth_registered/image_raw is published.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44705/new-openni.launch-file---%3E-topic-gone/) by [Pitscho](https://answers.ros.org/users/2751/pitscho/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, the last update accidentally removed that topic.  I've reverted that change. You can use the fixed version from source (should only need to download openni_launch from source). The update should propagate into the debian files in the next day or so.

---

Originally posted by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) with karma: 606 on 2012-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-10-01**:
Nice to hear, experienced the same. -- Does this include this issue [44893/initialize-but-topics-are-empty](http://answers.ros.org/question/44893/initialize-but-topics-are-empty/), too?

**Comment by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) on 2012-10-04**:
I don't think so - other topics should still be getting published. This bug should have primarily affected the depth image